# After Compile In Android Studio My APK Contents Are Dated 1980?

Tags: android, android-ndk, timestamp

Hello i have a rather small issue but in a small way its a massive issue as googleplay keep rejecting my app because of it.

Here is my issue:
[Screenshot the my apk contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG34b.png)

So all the files in my apk after compiling with a newly created keystore (or without and unsigned) are date at 1980 as in the picture above. my androidmanifest.xml is also the same?

This is really annoying i have tried timestamping methods here on stackoverflow without any success.

I have been throught the whole project in android studio for any related configuration in settings and code. i have re-installed android studio jkd,ndk,sdk and still its the same.

Anit help on solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: is your time and date on the PC correct?

Comment: yes i checked the OS time and date aswell as my bios.. those were the first things i checked.. Before compiling the files in source directory are correctly dated the date only sets to 1980 AFTER compiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intentional, it reduces changes between apks.

If you want to avoid this you can add the following setting to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.keepTimestampsInApk = true
```

According to my tests it will change only some of the timestamps (e.g. `classes.dex`) in the apk and keep some of the timestamps (e.g. `AndroidManifest.xml`).

*source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37116029*

Comment: True that, However it affects your Instant Run